# How to search wrapper query with OpenSearchClient in Java SDK?

Tags: java, opensearch, resthighlevelclient

I'm newbie to opensearch.

I'm working on utilizing the OpenSearch's Java SDK. 
I'know that this contain two java class for client:

1. `OpenSearchClient`
2. `RestHighLevelClient`

I know that `RestHighLevelClient` has been deprecated in elasticsearch 7.x, and conversion between camel case and snake case is not possible.

For this reason, while using the `OpenSearchClient`, I found that the wrapper query does not exist for the `OpenSearchClient`.

---

**So, What I want to ask is:** 
How to do wrapper query using `OpenSearchClient`?

---

**The current logic with `RestHighLevelClient` is:**

```java
String query = "{\"term\":{\"name.keyword\":{\"value\":\"bob\"}}}"

BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .must(new WrapperQueryBuilder(query));

RestClientBuilder builder = getRestClientBuilder();
SearchResponse searchResponse;
try (RestHighLevelClient highLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(builder)) {
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
            .query(queryBuilder).from(0).size(10);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = Requests.searchRequest("my_index")
            .source(searchSourceBuilder);   

    searchResponse = highLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT); 
}
```

Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Hello! Did you manage to fix the issue? I am also interested in the wrapperQuery method too

Comment: Unfortunally, seems to be not exist in `OpenSearchClient`.